# Javascript - Split a delimited text into columns

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to split a delimited text into multiple columns. So far I managed to add textareas dynamically, but I'm having trouble splitting the array twice ("\n" and the delimiter) and getting the columns. Below is an image of what I'm trying to do. I appreciate the help.

[image]

HTML

```
Total columns #<input id="colNum" value="4"> Delimiter <input id="delimiter" value="—">
<button id="splitText">Split</button>
<br>
<br>
<textarea id="input">
A1—B1—C1—D1
A2—B2—C2—D2
A3—B3—C3—D3
A4—B4—C4—D4
A5—B5—C5—D5
A6—B6—C6—D6
</textarea>

<div class="tb_table"><div class="tb_tr"></div></div>
```

JS

```
  var cols = $('#colNum').val();
  var delimiter = $('#delimiter').val();
  var text = $('#input').val().trim().split('\n');

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    $('.tb_tr').append('<div class="tb_cell"><textarea id="tb_col_' + (i + 1) + '"/></div>');

    col_arr = text[i].split(delimiter);

    temp = "#tb_col_" + (i + 1);
    $(temp).val(col_arr);
  }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kzmamuax/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create your textareas in a first for loop. And then use another loop to parse `text`. Otherwise you may end up trying to add data to a non existant textarea.

And in that other loop, you need a nested loop to loop through your splitted string.

[Your updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p85n8emu/)

```js
$("#splitText").click(function() {
    var cols = $('#colNum').val();
    var delimiter = $('#delimiter').val();
    var text = $('#input').val().trim().split('\n');

    $('.tb_tr').html('');
    
    var i, j;
    
    
    // first loop to create a textarea for each column :
    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        $('.tb_tr').append('<div class="tb_cell"><textarea id="tb_col_' + (i + 1) + '"/></div>');
    }

    // second loop to loop through data read in the text array 
    for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        col_arr = text[i].split(delimiter);

        // nested loop to loop through the splitted string 
        for (j = 0; j < col_arr.length; j++) {
            // using the right element name to add the text in the right textarea : 
            temp = "#tb_col_" + (j + 1);
            $(temp).val($(temp).val() + col_arr[j] + "\n");
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.tb_table {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.tb_tr {
  display: table-row
}

.tb_cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 200px
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 120px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Total columns #<input id="colNum" value="4"> Delimiter <input id="delimiter" value="—">
<button id="splitText">Split</button>
<br>
<br>
<textarea id="input">A1—B1—C1—D1
A2—B2—C2—D2
A3—B3—C3—D3
A4—B4—C4—D4
A5—B5—C5—D5
A6—B6—C6—D6</textarea>


<div class="tb_table">
  <div class="tb_tr">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for adding detailed comments and explanations. I appreciate it.